# How did the Tesseract end up with Mar Vell?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger, captain-marvel

In the end of Captain America, Tony Stark's father retrieves the Tesseract.

In Captain Marvel we are shown that Lady Marvel was working with the Tesseract.

How does the Tesseract go from Mr.Stark to Lady Mar Vell?

EDIT:
What I'm looking to find out is how does she take the Tesseract out of the Earth and stow it away on a space station without anyone knowing. Is there any clue that could tell us how Mar Vell gained so much clearance to Project Pegasus, that she could relocate the Tesseract without anyone in S.H.I.E.L.D knowing?

Comment: You better Look at this. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97831/what-is-the-history-of-the-tesseract-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe-taking-in/97863#97863

Comment: Unfortunately, neither does the question nor the answer focuses on the specific issue that I have raised in my question. The link is more a general list of ownership.

Comment: However, https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97621/how-did-s-h-i-e-l-d-lose-ownership-of-this-item this is exactly what I have asked.

Comment: I've updated the question as I'm looking for something more specific and not just that Mar Vell was part of Project Pegasus.